# Delete each letter before passing on the next array index?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, if-statement, iteration

I've been writing this little script in order to make a "self writing text" animation. The thing is, everytime a word is finished, it jumps straight up to the next one. I can't work my head around it to make so each letter deletes before passing on the next word in the array.

```
const text = ['design', 'make', 'develop', 'code', 'create']
let count = 0;
let index = 0;
let currentText = "";
let letter = "";

(function type() {
    if (count === text.length) {
        count = 0;
    }
    currentText = text[count];
    letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);
    
    document.querySelector(".main__animation").textContent = letter;
    if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
        count++
        index = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(type, 500);
}())
```

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: _"make so each letter deletes before passing on the next word in the array"_ What does that mean? When a word ends, do you want to animate deleting each letter before displaying the next word? If so, do you want to delete left-to-right or right-to-left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const text = [, 'design', 'make', 'develop', 'code', 'create']
let count = 1;
let index = 0;
let currentText = "";
let letter = "";
var deleting = false;

(function type() {
  if (count === text.length) {
    count = 1;
  }
  currentText = text[count];

  if (deleting) {
    letter = currentText.slice(0, --index);
  } else {
    letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);
  }

  document.querySelector(".main-animation").textContent = letter;
  if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
    deleting = true;
  }
  if (letter.length === 0) {
    count++;
    index = 0;
    deleting = false;
  }
  setTimeout(type, 500);
}())
```

```html
<div class="main-animation"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came along. Please let me know if there is any doubt.

```js
function createAnimation(words, target, speed) {
  let wordIndex = 0;
  let i = 0;
  let erase = false;
  
  const handler = () => {
    const word = words[wordIndex];
    
    if (erase) {
        target.innerText = target.innerText.slice(0, -1);
        
        if (!target.innerText.length) {
            wordIndex = (wordIndex + 1) % words.length;
            i = 0;
            erase = false;
        }
    } else {
        target.innerText += word.charAt(i);
        i++;
        
        if (i === word.length) {
            erase = true;
        }
    }
  };
  
  let interval = null;
  
  return {
      start() {
          interval = setInterval(handler, 1000 / speed)
      },
      stop() {
          clearInterval(interval);
      }
  }
}

const animation = createAnimation(
  ['design', 'make', 'develop', 'code', 'create'],
  document.getElementById('target'),
  5 // [letters/s]
);

animation.start();

// TO STOP, CALL animation.stop()
```

```html
<h1 id='target'></h1>
```